Matrix inequality$\vert \vert \sum_{n,m} A_{n,m} B_m \vert \vert \leq max_{l}\vert \vert \sum_n A_{n,l} \vert \vert\vert \vert \sum_m B_m \vert \vert$
I was trying to do some Trotter error bounds in the context of quantum computation.
Suppose for every positive integers $n$ and $m$ that $A_{n,m}$ is a matrix and $B_m$ is a matrix. Is it true that
$$
\vert \vert \sum_{n,m} A_{n,m} B_m \vert \vert \leq max_{l} \vert \vert \sum_n A_{n,l} \vert \vert   \vert \vert  \sum_m B_m \vert \vert? 
$$
I suspect it is not true, I tried to do some tricks with Cauchy Schwartz for vectors for matrices, but it did not work. What is a simple counterexample?
